# Excel: Evaluating a string (obtained through vlookup) as a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013

I have a list of formulas, as strings, in a separate worksheet (tbl2), such as the following:

```
0.01 * INDIRECT("RC[1]", FALSE) * 0.01
```

In the working sheet, one cell has the following formula that references one of those strings:

```
=VLOOKUP(B22, tbl2!B4:J68, 2, FALSE)
```

That returns the string-form formula. How can I turn the string into an actual formula to evaluate its result?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the vlookup in the indirect function?

Comment: @Wyatt Shipman: INDIRECT can't evaluate strings as formulas. It can only evaluate strings as cell references. As far as I know, there is not a formula evaluator without VBA or old Excel4Macros.

Comment: thanks @AxelRichter, I don't know that the OP INDIRECT formula will evaluate properly since it is expecting a full R1C1 reference and it is not an offset formula.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could try using **VBA** sorry -- say your formula is in `sh1:A1`, and result will be in `sh1:B1`. 
In my case (Excel2010), it can valuate formulas ; I believe it is ok if input string in A1 comes from Vlookup:

```
Public Sub this()
    mySheet = "sh1"
    Dim C As Object
    Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet).Range("A1:A1")
    For Each C In myrange
        C.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & C.Value
        C.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

In case your formula contains cells or ranges from a workbook, you can check [that one I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057429/count-number-within-slabs-through-excels-function-formula/36081262#36081262).