# Count number within slabs through excels function / formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count the amount between different value slabs. For Example

```
**Customer      Amount** 
A               100
B               300
A               500
C               700
D               900
E               1100
F               1300
G               1500
H               1700
I               1900
```

Desired result

```
**Solutions          Count**
Between 100-500         2
Between 500-1000        3
Between 1000-1500       3
Between 1500-2000       2
```

i tried it trough countif formula but it include a lot of efforts when there is huge data and lots of amount slabs are included

Comment: Repost of [Making counts between different value slabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054904/making-counts-between-different-value-slabs). Fix your existing problematic questions before creating new ones.

Comment: Your slabs overlap, unless you plan on excluding values on the border.  If you do not, your manner of defining them is inconsistent. This service  exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Take a look at the `FREQUENCY` function.

Comment: i tried but it did not work

Comment: @Attique Then clarify your question in accordance with my comment above, and with the guidelines in the links I provided in that comment above.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, I have a peace of code which generates the formula for the "slabs", and calculate the number of occurrences within.

Say you have your values in column C (beware for C only to contain numbers; to be sure you can also make it `$C$1:$C$1000$`or so), and the plots of your slabs start with 0 in `$D$14`. Output in column G (and debug in columns E - F)

With Function MakeR1C1:

```vb
Function MakeR1C1(A1Formula As String) As String

MakeR1C1 = Application.ConvertFormula( _
    Formula:=A1Formula, _
    fromReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
    toReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
    ToAbsolute:=xlAbsolute)

End Function
```

Then you can work with the below (I made only 10 slabs):

```vb
Public Sub it()
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap
    Dim wkRange As Range
    Dim inputRange As String
    Dim argFormula As String
    this_workbook = "MyWBook.xlsm"
    mySheet = "MySheet"
    ' Important: to make it work it is necessary to use WB+Sheet reference
    inputRange = "[" & this_workbook & "]" & mySheet & "!$C:$C"
    inputRange = MakeR1C1(inputRange)

    Set wkRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet).Range("D15:D25")
    ' D14: starting plot
    For Each C In wkRange
        upBound = C.Value
        lowBound = C.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        argFormula = "COUNT(" & inputRange & ") " & _
                 " - COUNTIF(" & inputRange & " ,"">" & upBound & """) " & _
                 " - COUNTIF(" & inputRange & " ,""<=" & lowBound & """)"
        C.Offset(0, 1).Value = argFormula
        C.Offset(0, 2).Value = "between " & lowBound & " and " & upBound
        C.Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & argFormula
    Next

Exit Sub
ErrorTrap:
    Beep
    MsgBox "FAILED" & Chr(13) & _
                    "arg: " & argFormula & Chr(13) & _
                    "Error number: " & Err & Chr(13) & _
                    Error(Err)
End Sub
```